# How can I reduce the number of buttons?

Tags: reactjs

I need to have only one button doing two things one by one. I have two buttons "Обучить" and "Генерировать" and they both do something onClick. Is it possible to do it all with one button?

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    style={{
        background:
            "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)"
    }}
    onClick={this.parseInput}
>
    Обучить
</Button>

<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    style={{
        background:
            "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68 90%)"
    }}
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.updateData(this.state.filterArray);
    }}
>
    Генерировать
</Button>
```

Comment: Please detail the question because it is not clear what is the desired behaviour

Comment: Why not make each button its own new component?

Comment: Have `this.parseInput` call `this.props.updateData(this.state.filterArray)`...?

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, I got stupid for a moment

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can use a variable to decide what action you want to perform on `onClick` function

```
onClick={() => {
   if(this.props.type == 'update')
      this.props.updateData(this.state.filterArray);
   else
      this.parseInput()
}}
```

You can use same property `type` (or anything you like) to render different labels

```
{{this.props.type=='update'? 'Генерировать': 'Обучить'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the same component but make them do different things, on click for example.

Here is an example of how you can do it.

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({onClick}) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      Click on me
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button;
```

So when you want to pass down a method to the button, you can do it like this.

```
import Button from './button';

clickerTicker() {
  alert("First method, clickerticker");
}

secondaryClick() {
  alert("Second method yo");
}

render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <ButtonComponent onClick={this.clickerTicker.bind(this)}/>
        <br/>
        <ButtonComponent onClick={this.secondaryClick.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Just pass the onClick to the component

Comment: Please provide relevant code on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. When that link goes stale, this answer will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to make a component reusable? In that case you might want to design your component like so.

```
const NewButton = ({onClick, children}) => (
  <Button 
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    style={{
      background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #00ACD3 30%, #00BE68)
    }}
    onClick={onClick}>
      children
  </Button>);
```

Then your above snip becomes

```
<NewButton onClick={someFunction}>Something</NewButton>
<NewButton onClick={otherFunction}>Something</NewButton>
```

This is the basic idea behind any component-based front-end framework and I suggest you go to the react tutorials to learn more.
Otherwise, there are plenty of good [articles](https://blog.bitsrc.io/reusable-components-in-react-a-practical-guide-ec15a81a4d71?gi=87f79955e85b) about the topic out there